# Integrating rational functions. $\int\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x^4-x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there really another way of solving this problem $$\int\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x^4-x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x$$
avoiding partial fractions decomposition? I have tried the partial fractions decomposition, but it is not serving me right.

Comment: Stop doing left\ , right\ without any symbol! This is what prevents your formula from looking nice. Edit your post.

Comment: ok thanks i highly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by _"not serving me right."_? It seems to be the standard and logical approach here.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Are you sure it's not supposed to be a definite integral? The indefinite solution appears to be quite nasty involving $\arctan$ and $i\sqrt{3}$, whereas $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2 - 3x + 1}{x^4 - x^2 + 1} = 2\pi$ is rather clean.

Comment: No it is not a definite integral its an indefinite integral and its the solution composition i really need

Comment: @Dando18 There's no need for complex parts in the indefinite integral, an anti-derivative is: $$\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)\arctan\left(2x-\sqrt{3}\right)+\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)\arctan\left(2x+\sqrt{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

The integral can be split into two pieces:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int {\frac{x}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}  &= \frac{1}{2}\int {\frac{1}{{{u^2} - u + 1}}du}  \\
&= \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\arctan \left( {\frac{{2u - 1}}{{\sqrt 3 }}} \right) + C \\&= \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\arctan \left( {\frac{{2{x^2} - 1}}{{\sqrt 3 }}} \right) + C
\end{aligned}$$

where $u=x^2$, and

$$\int {\frac{{{x^2} + 1}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}  = \int {\frac{{1 + \frac{1}{{{x^2}}}}}{{{x^2} + \frac{1}{{{x^2}}} - 1}}dx}  = \int {\frac{{d(x - \frac{1}{x})}}{{{{(x - \frac{1}{x})}^2} + 1}}dx}  = \arctan (x - \frac{1}{x}) + C$$

Therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
\int {\frac{{{x^2} - 3x + 1}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}  &= \arctan (x - \frac{1}{x}) - 3\left[ {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\arctan \left( {\frac{{2{x^2} - 1}}{{\sqrt 3 }}} \right)} \right] + C \\
&=
 \arctan (x - \frac{1}{x}) - \sqrt 3 \arctan \left( {\frac{{2{x^2} - 1}}{{\sqrt 3 }}} \right) + C
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Wow thanks a lot veterans the problem really took a lot of my sheets.

Comment: when you were splitting the numerator how did we get rid of the coefficient of the linear term (-3)?

Comment: @WilmotGray I've added this detail to my answer.

Comment: This is quite elegant. (+1)

Comment: ok thanks  for the splitting the numerator method love it its better off than the demanding partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $$\int\frac{x^2-3x+1}{(x^2-\sqrt{3}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{3}x+1)}dx=\\=\int\frac{x^2-\sqrt{3}x+1}{(x^2-\sqrt3{x}+1)(x^2+\sqrt3{x}+1)}-\int\frac{(3-\sqrt{3})x}{x^4-x^2+1}=\\\int\frac{dx}{x^2+\sqrt{3}x+1}-\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{2}\int\frac{2x}{x^4-x^2+1}dx$$
Now putting $u=x^2$ for the second integral
$$\int\frac{dx}{(x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{2}\int\frac{du}{(u-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}$$
Those two integrals can be made into $\arctan$ form I'll leave it to you.

Comment: I think you meant to cancel $x^2 - \sqrt{3}x + 1$ in the first antiderivative between lines $2$ and $3$, rather than $x^2 + \sqrt{3}x + 1$.

Comment: @Chri Yeah you're right, edited